# ¿Listen en hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Tengo esta clase [image: Clase que contiene la anotación que hace referencia a un listener]
el problema surge cuando hago  persistir una instancia no me reconoce el listener y no realiza la accion antes de persistir.

Answer (score 1):

puedes probar con la anotación @PrePersist, ella se va ejecutar automáticamente antes de insertar en la base de datos. Y creas el método que quieres que se ejecute durante esa acción. Sería algo así:

```
 @PrePersist
 private void metodoAEjecutar() {
    //Código a ejecutar
 }
```

Comment: Y si corresponde `@PreUpdate` tambien

Comment: Exacto tienes varios comodines para jugar: PrePersist, PreRemove, PostPersist, PostRemove etc. Puedes conseguir más información en la página oficial de Hibernate.

Comment: ya lo probé de esa manera pero aun así no quiere ejecutar mi método que le asigne.estaba investigando que a partir de hibernate 4.* se realiza de otra manera.

Comment: Muéstrame  la clase completa para ver como te quedó!!!!